# onClick prevents required validation. why?

Tags: reactjs

I have the following code:

```
function AddForm(props) {

const handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
    createService(uid, service)
}

return (

      <Form>
        <Form.Group controlId="serviceTitle">
          <Form.Label>Service Title</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control 
          name="serviceTitle"
          onChange={update}
          required
          />
        </Form.Group>
        <Button variant="primary" type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit}>
          Publish Service
        </Button>
      </Form>
);
}
```

For some reason, when I include `onClick={handleSubmit}` in the button, my `required` field validation don't work anymore. But when I remove `onClick={handleSubmit}`, the `required` works fine. How can I keep the required validation while also having it handleSubmit?

Comment: please add details about what lib you are using for forms

Answer (score 2):

Instead of onClick, you should use onSubmit in the Form tag.

> There are benefits for it such as
>
> 1. You can use "Enter" key to submit.
> 2. You can use HTML5 form validation such as **required** or **novalidate**.

In your case, it will enable you to use required attribute in Input

Comment: This is precisely the advice given in the duplicate I suggested.

Comment: have just read the post that you have mentioned. yea.. lots of people are using onClick event of button to submit forms nowadays. thanks for sharing the post.